# Could I use 'this' to introduce a person?

Tags: this-that

Which of the sentences below are correct?

> This’s my best friend, William.
>   Those’re my classmates, James and Harry.
>   That’s my teacher, Mrs Wilson.

UPDATE: I just took an exam. The correct sentence is the last one, but I don't understand why.

Comment: All of those look fine (although you wouldn't normally write _this's_ contracted, since it sounds the same as _this is_). Do you have reason to believe that some of them may be incorrect?

Comment: Also, I don't think you would normally write *Those're* for *Those are*, for the same reason given by Bradd.

Comment: The reason the last sentence is correct on your exam is because "_this's_" and "_those're_" are **not standard contractions in English**. I use them to save characters here in comment boxes, but not when writing formal English.

Comment: This is a wonderful example of a very bad exam question. Your (entirely understandable) focus on choosing among _this, those_ and _that_ meant that you were not even considering the grammar convention that the person who set the exam thought he was testing.

Comment: "this's" isn't a good contraction in written or spoken English. I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three are grammatically correct and can be used to introduce persons, but only *That’s my teacher, Mrs. Wilson.* is normally written. The first two are uncommon contractions in those sentences.

Which [demonstrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative) pronoun you use is a matter of [context](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/demonterm.htm).

> *This* implies that you're standing or sitting [close](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/pronouns/5/demonstrative-pronouns/) to your best friend, or else pointing to a picture of him.
>   *Those* implies that your classmates are farther away from you than your best friend is, or in a different part of the picture. Some native speakers might use *these* and others might use *they*.
>   *That* also suggests that your teacher is more distant from you than your best friend is.

You might also being using different pronouns because you like variety and don't want to say *this* every time.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing wrong with using *this* for a person. Basically, *this* can be used to point out anything nearby. If a person is near you, you can introduce him by pointing with *this.*

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please review [how to answer questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer), specifically “Writing style matters.” I edited your post to improve the style; please review it to make sure that I didn't change the meaning.